# angular2 and bootstrap-datepicker -- how to get the selected date?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use bootstrap-datepicker in angular2.

```
                <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker">
                    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" />
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>





    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: '2001-01-01',
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
        this.stupid_date = ev.date;
        console.log('dudeme',ev.date.valueOf(),ev.date )
    });
```

How do I get the selected date?  The console.log prints but the this.stupid_date is not updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the `this` inside your callback function doesn't reference to your component instance.

Try to use arrow function as follows:

```
}).on('changeDate', (ev) => {
  this.stupid_date = ev.date;
  console.log('dudeme',ev.date.valueOf(),ev.date )
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/gEV0MnSiB14rqugEpPEh?p=preview)**

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this